# Getting Bad Request on Uploading Video on twitter using TweetInvi

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

I have created an application and in that i am using tweetinvi to upload video to twitter. I am using the following code to upload video:

```
var videoBinary = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var videoMedia = Upload.UploadVideo(videoBinary);

Tweet.PublishTweet("test", new PublishTweetOptionalParameters()
{
    Medias = { videoMedia }
});
```

Video is uploaded successfully, you can see this from the following screenshot:

[image]

When publishing tweet the following exception is coming:

[image]

Comment: hello, could you share the information loicated in the TwitterExceptionInfos property of the error for which you shared the image.

Thank you

Comment: @Linvi thanks for reply but actually this exception is related to video. After getting the status of video i got the actual problem. My problem is solved now. thanks